# The Noble Plebian

Tags: society, humans, politics, earth-like, social-norms

I'm creating a civilization modeled after Rome and am trying to determine the social structure within it and am probably going to ask another question about it after this one. I was thinking about making the father of one of my characters a self made noble or a Noble Plebian, but am unsure how to go about it.

How exactly did one achieve the status of Noble Plebian and how did they differ from regular nobles in terms of social status and political power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hereditary nobility must believe that their superiority over the common folk is **inherited**. The idea of granting nobility based on personal achievements goes completely against the grain. If that self-made man was **just as good** as they are because of his achievements, they'd have to look at their own, personal achievements and not just those of their great-granddad. And likely they would fall far short of this newcomer, unless they stack the decks.

On the other hand, offering a way into the nobility allows the powers that be to co-opt people who would otherwise fight the established order.

That leads to a two-tiered nobility, just like Rome.

- First, there is the old nobility. The highest offices are reserved for them. Those would be the senatorial families.
- Then there is a new nobility where one can enter on merit. Those would be the equites.

The way from the new mobility to the old nobility takes several generations of **good behaviour**. Money or military success might get a commoner into the new nobility. And after many years, the old nobility might "forget" the common ancestry of the newcomers. It also helps if the rich newcomers marry into (non-inheriting) branches of the old nobility.

Google [noveau riche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_riche), [equites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equites), [adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_in_ancient_Rome).